# Dreamweaver Coding Hint won't go away

Tags: dreamweaver

I've had this issue several times and usually I can just shut down the program and restart it. But this time I have a bunch of windows open and I don't want to restart Dreamweaver.

My problem is that Dreamweaver brought up a code hint, but the code hint box now won't go away. It just sits there floating in the middle of the page. It doesn't matter if I click to Preview or any other tab in Dreamweaver, it still just sits on top of everything.

I'm working on a Mac, Dreamweaver CC (cloud, fully updated). Anyone else have this problem???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been a HUGE PAIN for me as well! You can make the code hint disappear though by finishing out an element that is in the code hint box.  For instance if the code hint box appears and you can see class in the drop down... create a `<div class="xyz">` real quick and the code hit box will dissipate after you close the quotes on the class because you used an element in that box.  As to why this continually happens on the Mac version I have no idea, but I hope they fix it soon!

Comment: If it is any consolation it happesn on the pc too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug since years as you can read here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/7745689
Someone suggests as a workaround to set the Coding Hint delay to 0 (as said here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/7745689#7745689) but for me, in Dreamweaver CC 2015 Windows fully updated via cloud app, this bug still occurs while I code JS files.
Awaiting for a final fix, I hope this suggestion can be useful for you on Mac. :)